# Is there a way to prevent restart during .exe file installation?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to install .net framework 4.7.2 via PowerShell script.
The thing is the default restart that accompanies this .exe installation.
I am trying to prevent this restart but can't find the right arguments
for the job.
This is my current snippet:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "$path" -ArgumentList "/quiet" -Wait
```

- $path is the dotnet .exe file.

I can't find documentation regards '-ArgumentList' options at all, or any efficient way to prevent this restart.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is probably better served on ServerFault or SuperUser SE sites.  You're looking for common msi commandline switches.

Comment: It is unlikely that you will be able to avoid the restart; the .NET Framework is heavily used by many standard applications and the OS (and PowerShell), and it is probable that .NET DLLs that are in use are also targeted for replacement by the new installation - thus, Windows will mark them for replacement, and require the reboot to actually _do_ the replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend giving the [admin guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/deployment-guide-for-developers) a read.

The switch you will need is `/norestart`. However, you may need to check if there is already a pending reboot on the system.

Comment: This seems to work. my problem was in another section of the code. thank you!